# Return multiple JSON as HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, json, httpresponsemessage

I have a `HttpResponseMessage` method that returns a JSON based on DB data:

```
public HttpResponseMessage RespMsg(JObject jsonData)
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
   dynamic json = jsonData;
   int recId = jsonData.Id;
   var respStructure = myTable.Where(r => r.Id==recId).Select(t => new 
      {
         t.Id,
         t.Name
      }
   var responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(respStructure);
   response.Content = new StringContent(responseJson, null, "application/json");

   return response;
}
```

The response I get is something like `{"Id":3,"Name":Third}`.
The row in T1, has multiple rows in table T2

```
var t2Resp = T2.Where(c => c.T1Id == recId);

foreach (var t in t2Resp) {
 //call a method that return an object with computed data
}
```

Is there a way to add the data from `foreach` as separate `JSON` like `{"Id":3,"Name":"Third"} {first data from foreach} {second data from foreach}`? The first one is from `T1` query and the next ones depending on `t2Resp` length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:-  First You have to create a DTO object that matches with your response. Since T1 and T2 have one-to-many relationship create a DTO class with below structure.

```
 public  class DtoData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DaatFromT2> T2Data { get; set; }
}

public class DaatFromT2
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
    public DateOnly prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to use this class to populate data from T1 and T2 and finally sterilize to JSON. Something as shown below .

```
    var resposeStructure = new List<DtoData>();

    var t1data = myTable.Where(r => r.Id==recId).Select(t => new
    {
        t.Id,
        t.Name
    };
   var t2Resp = T2.Where(c => c.T2Id == recId);
   foreach (var t in t1data)
    {
        var data = new DtoData
        {
            id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name,
            T2Data = t2Resp.Where(c => t.id == t2Resp.someid)
            .Select(t => new
            {
                //call a method that return an object with computed data
                //and map to corresponding properties
            });
        }
     resposeStructure.Append(data);
   }
  var responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(respStructure);
```

May be theses code snippets give you some idea and able to sort this issue.
Happy coding :)